# how can UILabel look like UITableViewStyleGrouped?

Tags: iphone, uilabel

how can my UILabel look like as UITableViewStyleGrouped of TableView?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the top of the source file:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

To set up the label:

```
label.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
label.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
label.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
label.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
```